# Should I use hostname or IP address for mongodb connection string

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

I've set up a MongoDB replica set with 3 nodes. All servers live in the same VPC, but in different availability zones. Thanks to `etc/hosts` file, in while I describe where to find the other nodes, my replica set is able to communicate between nodes. My `etc/hosts` file looks like this on all 3 nodes.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost mongo0.example.com
Private IP 1 mongo0.example.com
Private IP 2 mongo1.example.com
Private IP 3 mongo2.example.com
```

Now, the app server needs to connect to the replica set. Should I use the IP addresses of the nodes in the connection string or should I use the hostnames?

`mongodb://private_ip1:27017,private_ip2:27017,private_ip3:27017/dbname?replicaSet=rs0`
or
`mongodb://mongo0.example.com:27017,mongo1.example.com:27017,mongo2.example.com:27017/dbname?replicaSet=rs0`

If it's the latter (hostnames), should I configure the app server's `/etc/hosts` like each of the mongo nodes?

Answer (score 2):

Using IP address is usually a bad idea, as many times they may need to be changed. If at all possible I would stick with hostnames.

And yes, you will need to ensure that all replica members **and** any app servers or client machines can resolve the names (using /etc/hosts if necessary).

See also [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78464/is-it-correct-to-use-ip-addresses-instead-of-hostnames-while-configuring-mongo) for a more thorough explanation.